# JVM won't terminate

Tags: java, jvm, terminate

I have a simple test run of some medium-complexity code that won't terminate, i.e. the main method finishes but the process does not die.

Here is a rundown of the code (which is too long to be pasted here):

- `ProcessBuilder` is used to create a bunch of subprocesses. They all die properly (if you can believe VisualVM).
- We use log4j.
- The main algorithm runs inside a `FutureTask` on which `run` and later `get` are called.
- We don't explicitly use RMI, even though the list of threads seems to suggest so.

Obviously, I can call `System.exit(0)`, but I'd like to know what is amiss here. I have not been able to produce a minimum failing example. Also, I can not identify an obvious culprit from the thread list; maybe you can?

[image: from VisualVM after main terminates]

**Edit:** See [here](http://pastebin.com/XHEjuaxg) for a thread dump.

Comment: Have you tried jstack -l <pid> to see the thread stack?

Comment: And what should I be looking for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135682/whats-the-proper-action-plans-to-debug-the-dead-lock-issue-if-its-in-the-produc Not sure, but I guess if you print the stack info here, it will help others here to find your problem.Especially thread of your own program not JVM.

Comment: Added link to thread dump above. Looks pretty inconspicuous to me.

Comment: RMIReaper thread is known to lead to such problems; are you sure you are not using RMI implicitly (via Spring or some other wrapper)?

Comment: Turns out, I do use a class extending `UnicastRemoteObject`. Even though I never use it as an remote object, unexporting it did the job. Thanks a lot, Scorpion! Can you write up an answer for future reference and for me to accept?

Comment: It all looks correct from whatever the details you have given. My first suspicion was the sub-process, but they are terminated. And neither you have used any ExecutorService. Some more information needed

Comment: @Rapheal, I find a link talking about this issue  http://www.thatisjava.com/java-core-apis/45049/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scorpion lead me to the right answer:

`RMI Reaper` is something like a garbage collector for remote objects, e.g. instances of (subclasses of) `UnicastRemoteObject`. It is a non-daemon thread and therefore blocks JVM termination if there are still exported objects which can not be cleaned up.

You can explicity force remote objects to be cleaned up in this sense by passing them to `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(., true)`. If you do this on all previously exported objects, `RMI Reaper` terminates and JVM is free to shut down.

Answer (score 2):

You mention FutureTask. The first thing that comes to my mind is: are you using ExecutorService and forgetting to shut it down?

The second thing that comes to my mind is: are you reading to the end all the streams from the process? I worked with subprocesses long ago, and I don't remember exactly, but. I had problems similar to what you described, and by reading the streams to the end the problem would misteriously disappear!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only instantiate a `FutureTask` and let it do its thing, no `ExecutorService` involved (that I knew of). Depending on the exit code, I read output or error stream of the subprocesses and close them. Do you think reading both in any case might help?

Comment: By the way, a minimum example using a `FutureTask` the way I do failed to reproduce the behaviour.